# How to get memory speed value using C++ for linux?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I m working on Ubuntu 20-04 and I need the memory speed value in my code. I tried to execute the command "**sudo lshw  -C  memory | grep -i clock**" from popen function, but sudo needs a password. How to work with sudo without password in C++ for this case only? or is there another way to get the **memory speed** value using **C++** language?

*Note:* does /dev/mem contain this value? if yes how to map it?

Comment: You could give your user the permission to run `lshw` without entering a password; see [/etc/sudoers](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers)

Comment: What do you even need this for? The value isn't particularly meaningful. Systems with the same memory clock can have vastly different memory bandwidth.

Comment: @JonathanS. I need this value to estimate the execution time of my program in different machines. actually I m working on 2 machines: one with 1600MHz memory speed and the   other with 2133MHz. the time execution is different that's why I need this value.

Comment: I'm 99% sure the execution time has nothing to do with the memory bandwidth. That only matters when you're actually hitting maximum memory bandwidth. What CPUs do those systems have? 1600MHz vs. 2133MHz sounds like DDR3 vs. DDR4, which means that the system with 2133MHz memory just has a way faster CPU. Memory clock is meaningless for estimating a system's overall performance.

Comment: You'll never be able to get any meaningful information from that. Your two systems likely have different CPU clock speeds, whose instructions are decoded differently, whose memory pages are allocated differently, whose currently process priority list is different, whose memory subtimings are different, whose disk timings are different, whose page file usage is different. Given all of the differences that exist between these two systems both in hardware and current execution state it is impossible to meaningfully calculate the speed of one based on another.

Comment: @JonathanS. system  with 1600MHz has 3.4 GHz as CPU base speed, and the other system(2133,Hz) has 2.3GHz

Comment: That is also meaningless. Base speed is not the actual clock frequency the CPU runs at, and it also doesn't say anything about how much work the CPU gets done in each clock cycle. Please tell us the actual CPU model numbers.

Comment: @JonathanS.    the system with 2133MHz "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v3 @ 2.30GHz " and  the one with 1600MHz "Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz"

Comment: Do you have an estimate at all for the ratio between memory access instructions and other ones in your *programme*??? An estimate for their difference in time (memory access is slower, but an optimising compiler might pre-fetch earlier to reduce overhead)? Do you have an estimate for cache locality? If you don't, then even knowing exact hardware won't help much (and even if you have, probably won't, as there are too many other conditions).

Comment: I'd rather go with a mile stone strategy: Define specific mile stones within your programme when you know some specific percentage of the overall task is completed – the more you can define the more precise you will get. Measure time until receiving these mile stones and then estimate upwards from there how much time you will need for the remaining task...

Comment: @Aconcagua, Actually we don't have that ratio for now, but we're checking what parameters other than the CPU speed, cores count, .. can affect the performance of the machine. Cache locality we didn't include in the estimation. Can you suggest a resource to give an approximate idea what helps in the hardware performance comparison

Comment: @Aconcagua, The issue is we need a first program time estimation before any milestone is started, but what you mentioned can help refine the algorithm.

Comment: How much time can you effort to delay the very first estimate? Maybe you get more precise estimates if you run some kind of minimalistic benchmark on the respective system? Just a few hundred milliseconds perhaps, that won't be noticable as there's some delay for loading the programme from disk anyway!

Comment: @Aconcagua, Correct, we're benchmarking meanwhile as well. But first time estimation should be output really quickly, couple seconds

Comment: Couple seconds is a *lot* of time to reach some very first mile stone... Honestly, if you can afford *that* much time I cannot imagine why you shouldn't be fine with...

Comment: Profile your program to see what it's actually doing. Since you're on Intel, you can use the VTune profiler to figure out what exactly the CPU is doing and why it's running slow (or just use perf). Then you can build a benchmark (representative of the actual program) that tests how fast the system actually is. Here's another thing to think about: A system with four-channel 1600MHz memory has four times as much memory bandwidth as one with only a single channel. The clock frequency is the same, yet one system is 4x as fast. Clock frequency doesn't tell you anything.

Comment: Thank you, we will take into consideration your suggestions. What Kind of parameters affect the system's performance that s what we're checking.